# Perl - error reading text file

Tags: perl

I am trying to read a file in perl.

I just want to print the names of each line of file `players.txt`.

I am using this code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
open (MYFILE, 'players.txt');
while () {
    chomp;
    print "$_\n";
}
close (MYFILE);
```

This produces this error:

```
./program5.pl: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `MYFILE,'
./program5.pl: line 2: `    open (MYFILE, 'players.txt');'
```

I am using a Unix operation system to do this. I can't find a guide that works for reading in a file in Perl.

Comment: You should check that the `open` succeeded, and the `while` loop should read lines from the file. As the loop is now, it just iterates forever without reading anything

Comment: Use `open my $file, '<', 'players.txt' or die "$!:players.txt";`

Comment: What you show altogether doesn't make sense; the second line of your program is fine (even as there is a better way) and shouldn't throw a syntax error.  What's wrong is `while ()` -- there must be something in `()`.  To read from `MYFILE` filehandle it's `while (<MYFILE>)`.  Then the program should work. But open the file using code in Pursell's comment above.

Comment: `[can't] find a guide that works for reading in a file in Perl` What *did* you find? What version/implementation of Perl do you (intend to) use? Do you know [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_a_file_line_by_line#Perl)?

Comment: @Borodin Interesting, didn't know it's intended.  In my opinion, allowing such syntax is just a design bug. For one, we can't say `if ()` or `for ()` (not that I would want to)

Comment: @zdim: You can write `for ( ; ; ) { ... }` which has the same effect as `while()`

Comment: @Borodin  Right (and I used that form for a period of time) -- but there is _something_ inside `()`, and it's rather distinct.  The `while ()` freaks me out a little

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The errors you're getting are bash errors, which means that you're asking bash to process Perl code. That isn't going to work

At a guess, your shebang line `#!/usr/local/bin/perl` doesn't start at the beginning of the very first line. The two characters `#!` must be the first two bytes of the file

Alternatively you can drop the shebang line if you specify that `perl` should run the program:

```
perl program5.pl
```

You also have an error in `while ()`, which is an endless loop and doesn't read from the file. You need

```
while ( <MYFILE> ) {
    ...
}
```

You have found a very poor and old-fashioned source of advice to learn Perl. I suggest you take a look at the
[Perl tag information](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info)
which has a list of many excellent tutorials and resources

Comment: "perl myprog.pl" worked. I dont know what is wrong with "#!/usr/local/bin/perl". That must not be the right path to the perl directory. At least i can run my program now though, thanks!

Comment: @Some: Use `type -a perl` to show you where `perl` is.